# my first hidden UL set as display: none; affecting second UL

Tags: html, css

I have two UL sections, the first one by default I was setting to display: none; and changing it to display: block and then setting the second to display: none; based on a change in a select input.

inside each of my list items is a check box and a label tag.

for some reason when the first list is hidden any length that it goes down the other displayed list disallows me to click the label of the check box to select it.

so in the below if I set in my css to have #first {display: none;} I then can not use the label for "Second Option 1" to select its check box. Check box itself still functions as expected.

I tried applying a z-index to the label but it didn't seem to have any impact. I have not tried moving the list off in a negative location yet but just curious if I have to deal with it or if I am missing something.

Obviously the source below is minimal compared to the other markup I have so it could be entirely related to another portion affecting it.

Browser is IE9.

```
<div id="barcodes">
 <ul id="first">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" />
      <label for="1">First Option 1</label>
    </li>
 </ul>
 <ul id="second">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" />
      <label for="1">Second Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2" />
      <label for="2">Second Option 2</label>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

- Edited to reflect my actual code I was having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found my issue by means of the two fiddle options I was checking out below. Headed me in the right direction.

Issue was actually related to my ID tag that I didn't have in the markup above.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" />
```

I actually had the following markup in my page.

http://jsfiddle.net/mAGf4/

I forgot I copied a sub section of another list and made additions.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7FJm8/)

```
#first :first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `"` on the checkbox type this probably causes this mess.

Works: http://jsbin.com/dolegada/1/edit

Comment: that was just a terrible quick type problem, and certainly does cause problems.